# Querying two tables, from code

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate

I have two tables.

the first table: **Employee**

```
IdEmployee
Name
LastName
```

The second table: **CommentsEmployee**

```
IdComment
IdEmployee
Note
```

make consultation with the IdEmployee in the two tables, get Name, IdComment, and Note from C#
Tables are of type SQL
was trying

```
DetachedCriteria criteria1 = DetachedCriteria.For<Employee>()
                                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IdEmployee", 2))
                                .SetFetchMode("Name", FetchMode.Eager);

                DetachedCriteria criteria2 = DetachedCriteria.For<CommentsEmployee>()
                                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IdEmployee", 2))
                                .SetFetchMode("IdComment", FetchMode.Eager)
                                .SetFetchMode("Note", FetchMode.Eager);

                var result = session.CreateMultiCriteria()
                    .Add(criteria1)
                    .Add(criteria2)
                    .List();
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
otherwise

```
var result = session
                        .CreateCriteria<Employee>()
                        .CreateCriteria("CommentsEmployee")
                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("IdEmployee", f))
                        .List();
```

anyone can help me

Comment: What? Could you clarify your question?

Comment: I've tried to tidy your question up a bit but it still doesn't make a lot of sense - you may want to rephrase the text and actually include a question if you want an answer.

Comment: In your question, you should state what kind of tables you're talking about (i.e.: Linq-to-Sql, DataTables, collections, etc.) what you're trying to achieve, and what you've done so far that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for a simple join statement?

```
SELECT * FROM Employee JOIN CommentsEmployee ON Employee.IdEmployee = CommentsEmployee.IdEmployee;
```

That's generic SQL, I hope it works for you but at least it should convey the concept.

Comment: I'm relatively new to SO. But I wonder why this answer was downvoted without comment. This is as good answer as one can give to the question that was posted without a single question mark.

Comment: @Olaf: I used to wonder about such things as well, but then it went away.  Downvotes without comment simply happen, it's not a big deal.  I just try my best to answer the questions! Indeed, it was difficult to be sure what the question really was here, but I got the impression that this was the information they were seeking.  Hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at bag. Add the comments as a bag to employee and you only need 1 get/load statement.

The Employee class:

```
IdEmployee
Name
LastName
IList <CommentsEmployee> Comments
```

The xml for the bag:

```
<bag name="Comments" inverse="false" lazy="true" cascade="save-update" generic="true">
    <key column="EmployeeId"/>
    <one-to-many class="EmployeeComments">
</bag>
```